# Does collinearity largely impact the performance of neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, multicollinearity

I am build a neural network (NN). Its input include the parameters of a distribution, e.g., mean, median, standard deviation.

For example, I am using NN to predict the height of a person. The input features include some attributes of the person. A subset of the attributes are the parameters of the height distribution of all people from the same country. The parameters are like the mean, median, and std of the distribution.

Does this introduce collinearity problem to the NN? Does this impact the accuracy of the prediction?

Comment: Just make sure I understand what you're doing: you're using both the attributes of the individuals, and the fitted parameters of the distribution of the same group of individuals as input to your NN?

Comment: @horaceT Yes. Just concatenate them into a big input vector. Say the first 1-20 are individual attributes, and the 20-25 are the parameters of the distribution observed from the training data.

Comment: OK, so your concern of collinearity is about the mean being just the sum of the individual heights?

Comment: @horaceT Kind of. The nationality of a person has collinearity with the distribution parameters because each country has a set of distribution parameters. Also, the collinearity may also occur among the distribution parameters, e.g. Mean and median(?). I am wondering whether collinearity matters in NN and whether it can largely impact the prediction outcome.

Comment: If the goal of your model is prediction, answer is no. NN doesn't know and doesn't care about collinearity. But collinearity does impact performance in the way that noise variables inflate confidence intervals, and collinearity makes it hard to identify the true relationships betwn response and predictors.